I couldn't able to pull the API gateway rules from the Zoho Catalyst console
I'm trying to pull the API gateway rules to the local machine by running the catalyst pull command.  It throws an error of "The Login Redirect rule cannot be verified since the Client is not valid".
You can check on the complete error log below.
× Error: The client source directory D: \Projects\zohotest\APIrules mentioned in the catalyst.json file does not exist.
Please specify a valid source directory for the client or create a new Client by executing the catalyst client:setup command.
REF: https://www.zoho.com/catalyst/help/cli-client.html

Error: The Login Redirect rule cannot be verified since the Client is not valid.
Please rectify the errors in the Client to continue.
REF: https://www.zoho.com/catalyst/help/cli-apig.html
Login Redirect rule cannot be verified since client package is not valid
× An unexpected error has occurred.


As I checked from the error log, you are trying to pull the API gateway rules without having the Web Client on your local machine. Hence, you are facing this issue.
To resolve this issue, try pulling the Catalyst Web Client by running the command catalyst pull and select both the Client and API Gateway Rules.
